# Gatling (and JMeter) struggling to maintain Requests per Second (RPS)?

Tags: java, api, jmeter, performance-testing, gatling

I'm load testing an API. We have a problem - our response times are too large, sometimes close to a minute. We want to be at the range of under a second. But that is besides the point.

When I use a load testing tool, such as Gatling, the RPS sent seem to hit a halt. As you can see in the attached image, there is an initial 15 seconds of 20RPS, and suddenly almost no RPS at all. How can I maintain constant RPS? Probably it has to do with the poor response times, but what if I don't care about the response times? I just want the RPS constant.

My initial tests with JMeter also show similar behaviour.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What injection strategy are you using? How scenario looks? Is every user making one request, chain of requests or any of above in a loop?

Assuming that you want to test single endpoint, best approach to get constant requests per second (not constant responses as you already know) is to use scenario that executes single request and strategy that injects constant number of users per second fe:

```
setUp(
  scn.inject(constantUsersPerSec(25) during(15 minute))
)
```

If your user performs more then 1 requests there is option to throttle requests, but you need to remember that it will only throttle down not up, so you need to make sure that active users will make enough requests per second to reach that limit fe:

```
setUp(scn.inject(
  constantUsersPerSec(10) during(15 minutes)
).throttle(
  jumpToRps(25), holdFor(15 minutes)
))
```

So here if fe. single user makes 5 requests you can reach even 50 req/s but it will be throttled to 25. But you must remember that new users will be added every second so if it takes more time to finish 1 user then number of active users will increase. Also if response time is high then active users may not produce enough req/s since most of their time is waiting for response.

Comment: I have been using exactly the second code piece you have provided to get the RPS pattern in my original post. Response time is high, so active users spend a lot of time waiting for response. How can I maintain constant RPS with this limitation? Can I increase number of resources on my machine or something else?

Comment: Just increase number of users added to simulation. As long as you wont hit maximum number of open connections, open sockets etc. you are fine. And with 20 r/s you should not. I've just tested case with 30-60 second responses, and with 40 constant users per second i've managed to reach 20 req/s. Too be honest when I look at yours chart it looks weird, since gatling continuously adds new users it should also send new requests, but yours ends after just 15 seconds. Are you sure that its a test problem not system under test dying after receiving first few hundred requests? Can you show some code?

Answer (score 0):

In JMeter, You can achieve that by using [Constant Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer) at your test plan level.

Constant Throughput timer allows you to maintain the throughput of your server (requests/sec). Constant Throughput Timer is only capable of pausing JMeter threads in order to slow them down to reach the target throughput. Also, it works only on a minute level so you need to properly calculate the ramp-up period and let your test run long enough.

Let's see a brief thought on this:

To achieve the target throughput, you need to have enough number of threads in your test plan.

To calculate the number of threads you need for this test, you can use the below formula:

> RPS * max response time in second

In your case, If you want 20 RPS and your max response time is 60 seconds, you need at least 1200 (`20*60=1200`) Threads in your test plan.

As Constant Throughput Timer works on a minute level, to achieve `20 RPS` you have to configure your "**Target Throughput**" value to `1200/min` and **"Calculate Throughput based on"** value as "`All active threads`".

**Constant Throughput Timer Config:**

[image]

Now, if you have more than single requests in your test plan (i.e `4 requests`), then `1200 requests/min` will be distributed among `4 samplers`. That means you will get `5RPS` for each sampler.

Now, for the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) configurations, as you have mentioned **"Calculate Throughput based on"** value in Constant Throughput Timer for "`All active threads`", so all of your `1200` threads need to be started on the server to achieve that `20 RPS`. Use **Ramp-Up Period** config to control these threads to start.

**Ramp-Up Period** is the time in which all the threads arrive on your tested application server. So if you use `60 seconds`, then it will take 60 seconds to start all of your `1200 threads`. 1200 threads will be active in `60 seconds`.

You also need to set your test duration accordingly. Say, you want to keep that `20 RPS` for `5 minutes`. In this case, you have to set your test duration for `7 mins` (2 min extra is for: Starting 1 min for 1200 threads to start which is the ramp up time and last 1 min for the 1200 threads ramp-down time). Don't forget to check the loop counts to `Forever` if you are using [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group).

**Thread Group Config for the above-mentioned scenario:**

[image]

You can also use another handy JMeter plugin which is [Ultimate Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/) if you are confused with the default [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) configurations. You can download JMeter Plugins by using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/).

**Here is the Ultimate Thread Group Config for the above-mentioned scenario:**

[image]

Now while after the test finishes, you can check those `5 minutes` results where all of your 1200 threads were active by using the [Hits Per Second Listener](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HitsPerSecond/) and as well as [Active Threads Over Time Listener](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/).

Do not use JMeter GUI for Load testing, use the Non-GUI mode. Also, remove assertions if you have any in your test plan while you're trying to achieve some target RPS.