# Controlling number of Samples in bzm - Concurrency Thread Group

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

I am trying to find out throughput of an endpoint using Apache Jmeter as testing tool.
I need to hit the endpoint at `n threads(users) per second`, and every thread should fire exactly one requests(sample).
For the above i configured **bzm - Concurrency Thread Group**.

#### Configuration One:

`Target Concurrency: 100
 Ramp Up Time(sec): 1
 Ramp-up Steps Count: 1
 Hold Target Rate Time(sec): 10`

#### Configuration Two:

`Target Concurrency: 1000
 Ramp Up Time(sec): 5
 Ramp-up Steps Count: 5
 Hold Target Rate Time(sec): 60`

What i expect is
a. Configuration One: only 1000 request must be fired in 10 sec.
b. Configuration Two: 60000 requests  must be fired in 60 sec i.e 1000/sec.

Answer (score 1):

As per your **test case** and **test duration** settings, I think, you are making confusion with the Threads and Requests.

**Threads** are virtual users. Threads and Requests aren't the same.

**Ramp up** is the time in which all the **users** arrive on your tested application server.

**Requests** are simulated by **samplers** but **threads** are the simulation of **users**.

***Please note-*** The total number of **requests** are related to **throughput**, Whereas the number of active threads performing the same activity is related to **concurrency**.

You can achieve your requirements by using [Constant Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer) at your test plan level.

Constant Throughput timer allows you to maintain the throughput of your server (requests/sec). Constant Throughput Timer is only capable of pausing JMeter threads in order to slow them down to reach the target throughput. Also, it works only on a minute level so you need to properly calculate the ramp-up period and let your test run long enough.

Here are the workarounds:

1. Calculate the number of threads you need to achieve your target throughputs. Formula is:

   > RPS * max response time in second
2. Use the Ramp-up periods for the threads to active accordingly.
3. Make the loop count value to `Forever`
4. Set the test duration accordingly.

As Constant Throughput Timer works on a minute level, to achieve `X` RPS you have to configure your "**Target Throughput**" value to `X*60/min` and "**Calculate Throughput based on**" value as "**All active threads**".

For example, if you need 1000 RPS, then "**Target Throughput**" value should be `60000/min` in [Constant Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer).

Check out my answers on these threads to understand your scenario more briefly.

1. [How should I calculate Ramp-up time in Jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39051339/how-should-i-calculate-ramp-up-time-in-jmeter/39056038#39056038)
2. [Struggling to maintain Requests per Second (RPS)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55136069/gatling-and-jmeter-struggling-to-maintain-requests-per-second-rps/55149767#55149767)

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for the answer, I configured Constant Throughput Timer as mentioned by you. and i am able to achieve my desired requests in Configuration One, the problem is in configuration Two, the desired requests are always low as expected. I expect around 60K requests by 1000 threads in 60 secs. Is there any other way to do achieve it???

Comment: Yep, I already answered this at point 1. To achieve such a higher number of requests per second you need to have enough number of threads. 1000 threads aren't enough to achieve 60k requests per min (1000RPS). So you need to calculate this first through the formula as it is dependent on your application response time! See the [second reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55136069/gatling-and-jmeter-struggling-to-maintain-requests-per-second-rps/55149767#55149767) I provided where I answered this briefly.